# Save data to database then load data to Listbox

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2010

I have 2 buttons that add to a `CheckListBox`. The first button adds a Delivery with the customer name, address and arrival Time.

The second button adds a pickup with Delivery Name and Delivery address

I also have a database table called customers with the following columns:
ID, Description, Customer Name, Customer Address, Arrival Time, Delivery Name, Deliver Address

I have about 10 records stored in the database at the moment

My question - how do I code it so that when my program starts it loads the records stored in my database into the `CheckListBox` and when I add a new delivery or a new pick up it saves it in the Customer table in my database? Also, if I edit or delete within the `CheckListBox` I want it to update my database table accordingly.

Comment: What is your app - webforms? Winforms? Console app? Also: what database access technology do you use - "raw" ADO.NET ? Linq-to-SQL? Entity Framework? As is, this question cannot be answered...

Comment: oh sorry, window form and I'm not really sure what database, i just watched a video on how to create a database in visual studio and went with that
video link : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NfLk1921Ydc

Answer (score 2):

From the looks of the video, you're using SQL Server.  You'll need to do a few things in order to get your program where you want it.  I'll try my best to get you there, with the information provided (this assumes you are learning and will keep things basic):

"How do I code it so that when my program starts it loads the records stored in my database into the CheckListBox"

You'll need to add this using statement at the top of your windows form class:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

Then, in the form_Load event, connect to your database and retrieve the rows from the customer table (not tested):

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Setup connection to your database.
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("user id=sql_userID;" +
                                   "password=password;server=server_url;" +
                                   "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
                                   "database=databaseName; " +
                                   "connection timeout=30");

        //Open connection.
        myConnection.Open();

        //Create dataset to store information.
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        //Create command object and adapter to retrieve information.
        SqlCommand  myCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Customers", myConnection);
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(myCommand);
        adapter.Fill(ds);          

        //Loop through each row and display whichever column you wish to show in the CheckListBox.
        foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables)
            checkedListBox1.Items.Add(row["ColumnNameToShow"]);
    }
```

The rest of your question is a bit vague because you don't explain how you are going to save a "new" record (with a button, what data is required, what data is the user actually inputting, input types, etc.) or how you are "deleting" a record.  This should get you on the right path though and help get you started.

Comment: Thanks, no errors with the code however its not loading the data in the `CheackListBox`

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on the foreach loop and debug it, does the dataset(ds) have records in it?  Does the CheckListBox have ANY items in it (if the wrong type is in there, it could put System.DataRow ad the text value for eachList Item).