# Delete record from MDF database

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I want to create simple application in C#. It should be windowsForms app, with service-based database added to project. In this I want to make table (`ID`, `name`, `second name`) and in program show name into `listBox`. Current name selected in `listBox` will be deleted (row will be deleted)

Can anyone help me how to do it? I have try with dataset, this is working, but after I close app and run it again, table is full with data again.

Comment: Are you using entity framework?

Answer (score 3):

For saving records into database and loading them in a listbox you can see..

- [save-data-to-database-then-load-data-to-listbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13544284/save-data-to-database-then-load-data-to-listbox)

Now,for deleting a record from a listbox you can code like this..

```
   protected void removeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ListBox1.SelectedItem.Text == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select an item for deletion.");
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= ListBox1.Items.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                if (ListBox1.Items[i].Selected)
                {
                    DeleteRecord(ListBox1.Items[i].Value.ToString());
                }
            }
            string remove = ListBox1.SelectedItem.Text;
            ListBox1.Items.Remove(remove);
        }
    }
```

For deleting that record also from database use like this..

```
private void DeleteRecord(string ID)
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("YOUR CONNECTION STRING");
    string sqlStatement = "DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE Id = @Id";

try
{
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, connection);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", ID);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
{
    string msg = "Deletion Error:";
    msg += ex.Message;
    throw new Exception(msg);
}
finally
{
    connection.Close();
}
}
```

Comment: In the catch, it would be better to throw new Exception(msg, ex) - by including the inner exception, you'll preserve the full stack trace.